# Button in custom cell, ViewController method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Here's my situation.

I've got the following storyboard:
[image: Storyboard]
So, I've got a ViewController with a container view in it and a tableViewController. This tableViewController is embedded in the ContainerView through control-dragging from the one to the other.

Now, I have the following classes:

A ViewController:
This is the class of the ViewController in the storyboard.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
  }

func printText(message: String, custom: SomeCustomType) {
print("Button in cell clicked and parameters passed successfully to VC")
//....
}
```

Then I've got a TableViewController to manage the tableViewController:
This is the custom class of the tableViewController in the Storyboard.

```
Class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCell.")
        }

        // Configure the cell...            

        return cell
    }

    //And other functions such as 'numberOfSections', 'numberOfRows'
}
```

And finally, I have a tableViewCell class to connect all the cell's outlets to, etc.:
This is the custom class of the custom tableViewCell that's in the tableViewController.

```
Class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBAction func buttonClickedInCell(_ sender: Any) {
  }

}
```

What I want it to do is when I press the button in the cell, I want the method in the VC to run. I have tried multiple things, but haven't come to a way to do this yet.

Comment: callbacks can be other good option.

Comment: Have you tried local notification for this..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a **delegate** for this.

In the storyboard, click on the embed segue and give it an identifier.

[image]

Make `ViewController` conform to `TableViewCellDelegate` and pass the instance of `ViewController` in `prepare(for:sender:)`.

Set the delegate of the cell to the passed `ViewController` instance in `TableViewController`'s `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. When the button is pressed, the method inside the view controller will be invoked.

### Delegate

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func tableViewCellButtonPressed(_ sender: Any)
}
```

### TableViewCell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonClickedInCell(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.tableViewCellButtonPressed(sender)
    }
}
```

## TableViewController

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    weak var tableViewCellDelegate: TableViewCellDelegate?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCell.")
        }

        cell.delegate = tableViewCellDelegate

        return cell
    }
}
```

### ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, TableViewCellDelegate {
    var tableVc: TableViewController!

    func tableViewCellButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        //do whatever you want after pressing the button
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "embedTable" {
            tableVc = segue.destination as! TableViewController
            tableVc.tableViewCellDelegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want a method in my ViewController class to be run, not in my TableViewController. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can simply extend the delegation pattern so that the containing view controller is the delegate of the cell, or the delegate method in the tableview controller calls a delegate method in the containing view controller (this is what I would do)

Answer (score 0):

If feasible in your project try `NotificationCenter`.

In your `ViewController` add these two methods:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.notificationCellButtonClicked(nsotification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "CellButtonClicked"), object: nil)
}

func notificationCellButtonClicked(nsotification: NSNotification) {
    // Your logic to perform

}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:"CellButtonClicked"), object: nil)
}
```

and then in your custom tableViewCell :

```
Class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBAction func buttonClickedInCell(_ sender: Any) {
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "CellButtonClicked"), object: nil)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but delegates are the way to go for me!